# Binding expression in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the list of items

```
<ul>
<li><a>ItemA</a></li>
<li><a>ItemB{{vm.count}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am preparing the list in angular in Controller:

```
vm.listofItems =[{"textDisplay":"ItemA","Statego":""},
                 {"textDisplay":"ItemB{{vm.count}}","Statego":""}];
```

After some service call I'll get  vm.count value? how to Bind now.

Comment: Need more details. Show what you tried.

Comment: Hi create a fiddle for ref : https://jsfiddle.net/nj5/2aej7btz/

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/ve6m31d7/
update your listofItems  when you get $scope.count value.

Comment: Thanks, @ManojLodhi. I also found the similar approach that is to Re-Int the links once the response for count is received from service.

Comment: Is their any other approach to have a 2 way binding without re-init the same list of items Obj[$scope.listofItems ]. As count changes it auto update into view. Thanks

Comment: check in answers.

Comment: where is the ng-repeat?  you show a `UL` snippet that you say is the "list of items", and then show an assignment of an array in JavaScript where you try to use HTML.  There isn't enough here to understand why you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just try this code, First of all i will suggest you to use $scope. I have assigned your listOfItems in watch of count, it will work for you, whenever you change the value of $scope.count

```
 $scope.count;
 $scope.$watch('count', function() {
    $scope.listofItems =[
         {"textDisplay":"ItemA","Statego":""},
         {"textDisplay":"ItemB" +$scope.count,"Statego":""}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Html

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='list in main.listofItems'>
        <a href="">{{list.textDisplay}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input ng-model='main.count' ng-value='main.count'> {{main.count}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.count = 90;
  vm.listofItems = [{
    "textDisplay": "ItemA",
    "Statego": ""
  }, {
    "textDisplay": "ItemB " + vm.count + "",
    "Statego": ""
  }];

  $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function() {
    return this.count;
  }), function(newVal) {
    vm.listofItems[1].textDisplay = "ItemB " + newVal;
    // console.log(' change ' , newVal);
  });
});
```

This the solution I figured out.Is this approach is correct?

jsFiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/nj5/ve4xmhtj/